# How convert TxOut CtxUtxo era to Plutus Map TxOutRef TxOut

Tags: plutus, cardano-node

At least can someone give a hint how to convert TxOut CtxUtxo era to TxOut Ctx era.
I found that it's possible to convert to Ledger.UTxO and then ...